# How to add multiple data in Parse in the same row at the same time

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mapkit

I'm using Swift code, and this code is able to store the data in the Parse, but it doesn't place it in the same row, if you could please give me some feedback on this, as I'm a self thought and beginner of coding. Thanks.

```
let newTransObject:PFObject = PFObject(className: "Transaction")
let pickUpTimeObject:PFObject = PFObject(className: "Transaction")
let cityObject:PFObject = PFObject(className: "Transaction")
```

// Set the Text Key to text of the messageTextField

```
newTransObject["pickup_location"] = self.myAddress.text
pickUpTimeObject["pickup_time"] = self.myTime.text
cityObject["pickup_city"] = myPlacement.locality
```

//save the PFObject

```
newTransObject.saveInBackground()
pickUpTimeObject.saveInBackground()
cityObject.saveInBackground()


self.myAddress.text = "\(myPlacement.locality!) \(myPlacement.administrativeArea!) \(myPlacement.postalCode!) \(myPlacement.ISOcountryCode!)"
self.myAddress.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()



[enter image description here][1]print("\(myPlacement.locality!) \(myPlacement.administrativeArea!) \(myPlacement.postalCode!) \(myPlacement.ISOcountryCode!)")
```

Comment: what happens when you use just 1 of the 3 objects (i.e. remove pickUpTimeObject and remove cityObject).  For example, let newTransObject:PFObject = PFObject(className: "Transaction") newTransObject["pickup_location"] = self.myAddress.text newTransObject["pickup_time"] = self.myTime.text
newTransObject["pickup_city"] = myPlacement.locality newTransObject.saveInBackground() self.myAddress.text = "\(myPlacement.locality!) \(myPlacement.administrativeArea!) \(myPlacement.postalCode!) \(myPlacement.ISOcountryCode!)"
self.myAddress.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create one PFObject and set the variable of just that. I didn't import Parse so I hope there are no errors.

```
let newTransObject = PFObject(classname: "Transaction")

newTransObject["pickup_location"] = self.myAddress.text
newTransObject["pickup_time"] = self.myTime.text
newTransObject["pickup_city"] = myPlacement.locality

newTransObject.saveInBackground()
```